# Get InnerText from XML via List

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xml, xml-documentation

I receive the following string back from a service as a list

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<feed version="0.3" xmlns="http://purl.org/atom/ns#">
<entry>
<id>1</id>
<title>Job 1</title>
<author>
<name>Jim James</name>
</author>
<modified>2018-08-10T14:50:46-04:00</modified>
</entry>
<entry>
<id>2</id>
<title>Job 2</title>
<author>
<name>John Smith</name>
</author>
<modified>2018-09-10T14:50:46-04:00</modified>
</entry>
<entry>
<id>3</id>
<title>Job 3</title>
<author>
<name>Paul Rain</name>
</author>
<modified>2018-06-10T14:50:46-04:00</modified>
</entry>
<entry>
<id>4</id>
<title>Job 4</title>
<author>
<name>Jim James</name>
</author>
<modified>2018-08-10T14:50:46-04:00</modified>
</entry>
</feed>
```

I am attempting to grab the value of name through inner text but unable to do so:

i.e

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(response); //assuming response is above xml string
XmlNodeList parentNode = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("entry");
foreach (XmlNode childrenNode2 in parentNode)
{
    var b = childrenNode2.SelectSingleNode("name").InnerText ?? string.Empty;
}
```

Instead I'm getting object is null exception.

```
 "ExceptionMessage": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.",
```

Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: The XML can't be deserialized because you're missing the `</author>` tag

Comment: The xml is incorrect. As @MindSwipe says it is missing the end author tag or it should be like this `<author />`. And the root node is missing but that could be because you provided a snippet and not the whole xml.

Comment: Aside from your XML being invalid, consider using `XElement`; the API is friendlier than `XmlDocument` (e.g. `from entry in XElement.Load(response).Elements("entry") select (string) entry.Element("name")`).

Comment: Hint : Test that xml is good in VS from menu : Project : Add New Item : XML File.  Then paste xml into view.  Errors will show up like compiler errors in the Error List.  Also missing tags will be indicated by red underlines.

Comment: Apologies - I've added the update to the xml to close </author>. Still same issue.  @JeroenMostert - Thank you for suggesting this approach. I tried foreach (XmlNode childrenNode2 in parentNode)
            {
                var x = (from entry in XElement.Load(response).Elements("entry") select (string)entry.Element("name"));
} but received "ExceptionMessage": "Invalid URI: The Uri string is too long."

Comment: `.Load()` loads from a URI or file. `.Parse()` is for when you have the whole thing as a string already. (Note that reading directly from a stream is generally more efficient.) With your updated XML, you will not find any nodes since they're in a non-default namespace -- read up on `XNamespace` and how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few problems here:

1. You are using the old `XmlDocument` API which has somewhat inconvenient handling of namespaces.  Specifically:

   - [`XmlNode.GetElementsByTagName(string)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.getelementsbytagname?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Xml_XmlDocument_GetElementsByTagName_System_String_) is *namespace-unaware*.  It matches on the "raw" qualified element name, possibly including the prefix.

     Of this method, Microsoft writes in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.getelementsbytagname?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Xml_XmlDocument_GetElementsByTagName_System_String_)

     > Note
     >
     > It is recommended that you use the `XmlNode.SelectNodes` or `XmlNode.SelectSingleNode` method instead of the `GetElementsByTagName` method.
   - [`XmlNode.SelectSingleNode(string)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.selectsinglenode?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Xml_XmlNode_SelectSingleNode_System_String_), conversely, *is namespace-aware* and selects only elements in the empty namespace.

     From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.selectsinglenode?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Xml_XmlNode_SelectSingleNode_System_String_):

     > If the XPath expression does not include a prefix, it is assumed that the namespace URI is the **empty namespace**. If your XML includes a default namespace, you must still use the `XmlNamespaceManager` and add a prefix and namespace URI to it; otherwise, you will not get a selected node.

   This inconsistency between the two methods explains why your code partly works, since all the elements in your XML document belong to the `http://purl.org/atom/ns#` namespace.
2. If you indent your XML, it becomes apparent that the `<name>` node is nested within a container `<author>` node:

   ```
   <feed version="0.3" xmlns="http://purl.org/atom/ns#">
     <entry>
       <id>1</id>
       <title>Job 1</title>
       <author>
         <name>Jim James</name>
       </author>
       <modified>2018-08-10T14:50:46-04:00</modified>
     </entry>
     <!--Other entries omitted -->
   </feed>
   ```

   Your call to `SelectSingleNode("name")` also fails due to the presence of this intervening element.

Thus the following code will work and correctly select your entry names:

```
var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(response); //assuming response is above xml string

var manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
manager.AddNamespace("atom", @"http://purl.org/atom/ns#");

var parentNode = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("./atom:entry", manager);
foreach (XmlNode childrenNode2 in parentNode)
{
    var name = childrenNode2.SelectSingleNode("./atom:author/atom:name", manager)?.InnerText ?? "";
    Console.WriteLine(name);
}
```

Sample fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UBAS7O).

Incidentally, this can all be done more conveniently with the [LINQ to XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/linq-to-xml-overview) API, completely avoiding the need to use `XmlNamespaceManager` and XPath and whatnot:

```
var xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(response);

var ns = (XNamespace)@"http://purl.org/atom/ns#";
foreach (var element in xmlDoc.Root.Elements(ns + "entry"))
{
    var name = element.Element(ns + "author")?.Element(ns + "name")?.Value ?? "";
    Console.WriteLine(name);
}
```

Sample fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bPwhVs).

Answer (score 0):

The sample given is not valid XML:

- It doesn't have a document element
- It doesn't have an XML declaration
- It contains unclosed opening elements `<author>`

I would not expect this to parse, for any of these reasons.

Nevertheless, a NullReferenceException doesn't properly communicate the reason for the failure, so it's possible there is something else going on here. Use your debugger to determine which line is throwing this exception.

Assuming that you've missed out some of the XML and it actually is valid, this could also be caused by not specifying the namespace of the element you intend to select. If a document has a target namespace `http://some-namespace`, `entry` is not the correct name to select by; you must include the namespace. `GetElementsByTagName` has an [overload with two arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.getelementsbytagname?view=netframework-4.7.2), where the second is the namespace.

Comment: Thank you for your response @Tom W. When I add the namespace XmlNodeList parentNode = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("entry", "http://purl.org/atom/ns#");
            foreach (XmlNode childrenNode2 in parentNode)
            {                
                var c = childrenNode2.FirstChild.InnerText; //This works returning first ID value
                var b = childrenNode2.SelectSingleNode("name").InnerText ?? string.Empty; //Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
                var d = childrenNode2.SelectSingleNode("/entry/name").InnerXml;  //Same error as above.

Comment: The namespace caveat applies to all elements; you must specify a namespace when selecting them by xpath, wherever they are in the document. Similarly to the previous problem, `"/entry/name"` doesn't match anything in the document because `name` and `entry` aren't the names of the elements in the document, because they have no namespace qualifier.